# Insert Group By count results into a table

Tags: sql, database, insert, count, group-by

How do you insert a group by count result into a table? I'm trying to insert a list of names with counts for each.

Thanks!!

Comment: What sort of table? What language? Are we talking about databases? What database are you using?

Comment: Sorry...  MySQL. Two column table. Trying to insert the result of a count.

Comment: For more background see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853363/query-a-list-of-names-from-one-table-that-appear-in-a-field-in-a-different-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a select query that gives you the result that you want, then you just put the insert in front of it. Example:

```
insert into NameCount (Name, Cnt)
select Name, count(*)
from Persons
group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the exact RDBMS you are using, but this syntax is common for the task:

```
insert into groupTable(name, count) 
    select name, count(*) as count from people 
    group by name
```

This supposes you already have created the groupTable table. Some engines allow you to create the table directly from the query

```
create table groupTable as 
    select name, count(*) as count from people 
    group by name
```